# How to push object to array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This is my code

```
$scope.studentDetails=[];

   $scope.studentIds={};
   $scope.studentIds[0]{"id":"101"}
   $scope.studentIds[1]{"id":"102"}
   $scope.studentIds[2]{"id":"103"}
```

in the above code when i select student `id:101` i got marks from services like

```
   $scope.studentMarks={};
   $scope.studentMarks[0]{"marks":"67"}
   $scope.studentMarks[1]{"marks":"34"}
```

next i select student `id:102` i got marks from services like

```
   $scope.studentMarks={};
   $scope.studentMarks[0]{"marks":"98"}
   $scope.studentMarks[1]{"marks":"85"}
```

finally i want to store student details in to one array like

```
$scope.studentDetails=[{"id":"101","marks":[67,34]},{"id":"102","marks":[98,85]}]
```

using angularjs.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are doing here at all, or even what your question is.  you show some objects being created, but then refer to them like they are arrays, and then you show an array which you seem to want to be a product of one of the objects plus an array representation of the other object.  Your syntax is all out of whack here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like its more of a JS question than angular.

What about the Javascript push method?

```
$scope.studentDetails.push({id: 101, marks: [67, 34]});
```

Comment: but second time when i select id=102 i got marks , then those student marks also push to same array

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure I understand.

`$scope.studentDetails[0].marks.push(74);`

Is that something that could be useful?

Comment: how are you selecting id = 102? Are you trying to use the student id as an index. such as: $scope.studentDetails[102]?

Comment: Thank You @jamesmpw , now i got solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) to add one object, or concat, to [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) array into another array. See the references.

Answer (score 1):

angularJS is just a library to extend Javascript. You push into an array just like you would any object in Javascript.

First off, you need to declare an array.

```
$scope.studentIds = []; // Array of student ids.
```

Then when you want to add, you push:

```
$scope.studentIds.push({id: "101"});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this naively you need to loop through the student ids and then loop through the marks object and adding it to your studentDetails object if the ids match:

```
var studentDetails = [];

for (var id in studentIds) {
    var studentDetail = {}; // this will be a single student
    var marks = [];    

    if (studentIds.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        for (var mark in studentMarks) {
            if (studentMarks.hasOwnProperty(mark) && mark.id === id) {
                studentDetail.id = id;
                marks.push(mark.marks);
            }
        }
        studentDetail.marks = marks;
    }
    studentDetails.push(studentDetail);
}

$scope.studentDetails = studentDetails;
```